# One to many relationship in Rails - MissingAttribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I don't understand why `s.pages << page1` doesn't work in Rails 4.1.1 (I'm in rails console).
More background to my question: I have a Subject.rb and Page.rb as models, defined as follows:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pages
    scope :visible, lambda { where (:visible => true) }
end
```

and

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs to :subject 
end
```

In DB\Migrate I have 2 migration files that have been executed:

```
class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :subjects do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.integer "position"
        t.boolean "visible", :default => false
        t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :subjects
  end


end
```

And for Pages:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        create_table :pages do |t|
            t.integer "subject_id"
            t.string "name"
            t.string "permalink"
            t.integer "position"
            t.boolean "visible", :default => false
            t.timestamps
        end
        add_index("pages", "subject_id")
        add_index("pages", "permalink")

    end

    def down
        drop_table :pages
    end

end
```

In rails console, I type s = Subject.find_by_id(1) and I get the expected result, the record from the subjects tables that has id = 1
Then, I type: `page1= Page.new(:name => "McCaine", :permalink => "first", :position => 1)`
and a record is created but not yet inserted in the database (so at this point it has page id = nil), because it needs to be linked with the subject it belongs to, first of all.
Hence, I type `s.pages << page1`
but I get this MissingAttribute error:

> ←[1m←[35m (1.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN   ←[1m←[36mSQL (4.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT
>   INTO "pages" ("created_at", "name", "permalink", "position",
>   "subject_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING
>   "id"←[0m  [["create d_at", "2014-06-08 17:48:22.843764"], ["name",
>   "McCaine"], ["permalink", "first"], ["position", 1], ["subject_id",
>   1], ["updated_at", "2014-06-08 17:48:22.843764"]]   ←[1m←[35m
>   (1.0ms)←[0m  ROLLBACK ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write
>   unknown attribute `page_id'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:72:in`
>   write_attribute'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:68:in
>   `write_attribute'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:390:in`
>   []='
>          ....

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Later edit: As shown by `rake db:migrate:status`, the Page model is up:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20140531184836  Create users
   up     20140601105035  Alter users
   up     20140601212417  Create subjects
   up     20140601212440  Create pages
   up     20140601212504  Create sections
```

Comment: Just as a debugging purpose.. Can you tell me the output of `rake db:migrate:status` ? This is just to test if the migration for the `Page` model is up or down..

Comment: Thank you for answering, Arup. Page model is up. I edited the question to indicate this.

Comment: Ok. On console.. Just type `Page` and tell me what you are seeing ?

Comment: Arup: `Page(id: integer, subject_id: integer, name: string, permalink: string, position: integer, visible: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)` is what comes up after typing Page.

Comment: some how associations sucks.. Can you do `rake db:rollback STEP=3` and then `rake db:migrate` ? and try again ( hope you are develop environment) ;)

Comment: Can you try my answer. Your migration file was not correct.

Comment: He's following the lynda.com tutorials for Ruby on rails, I have the exact same problem.  we have 3 Models, Page, Subject, Sections. page_id is defined in sections, but what we're trying to do here shouldn't even been looking at that sections table.       If I find a solution Ill post.

Sorry, I know this issue is about a year old, but its the most recent RoR tutorial on Lynda.com

Answer (score 0):

I am following the Lynda Tutorial as well.

It appears you're missing the underscore.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pages
    scope :visible, lambda { where (:visible => true) }
end
```

and

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    #belongs to :subject 
    belongs_to :subject 
end
```

I had the same error with a minor different problem.  I was using belongs_to in both Page and Subject.